# Facing issues when upgrading Struts from version 2.0.11.2 to 2.3.28.1

Tags: struts2, dojo

I have an application which is using Struts 2.0.11.2.The application is flagged as vulnerable due to the old version of struts.I am facing issues while upgrading the struts to version 2.3.28.1(this is the latest allowed version in our organization).
After a lot of research on google i understood that the Dojo classes are deprecated in the new struts version. However our project uses a lot of dojo tags.
I am aware of the alternative plugins such as Struts Jquery. But use of alternative plugins will involve a lot of code change and testing which is not feasible in the current time frame we have got.
Is there some way out to use the dojo tags with the struts to version 2.3.28.1?.
Can we somehow incorporate the struts2-dojo-plugin with the Struts version 2.3.28.1?.

i tried it myself but am getting stuck(details mentioned below)

What i tried:

1) I replaced the Struts core jar with struts2-core-2.3.28.1 jar.

2) Updated all the dependency jars as mentioned in the Maven repository.

3) Added struts2-dojo-plugin-2.3.20.1

4) Included in JSP-s

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>
<head><sx:head /></head>
```

The issue i am facing:

When i hit the JSP below is the error i get. Any help is highly appreciated.Let me know if you need any more details or information from my side.

```
FreeMarker template error (HTML_DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!)
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> parameters.pushId  [in template "template/ajax/submit.ftl" at line 103, column 6]

----
Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it.
----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #if parameters.pushId  [in template "template/ajax/submit.ftl" at line 103, column 1]
----

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:116)
    at freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException.newDesciptionBuilder(UnexpectedTypeException.java:60)
    at freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException.<init>(UnexpectedTypeException.java:40)
    at freemarker.core.NonBooleanException.<init>(NonBooleanException.java:44)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.modelToBoolean(Expression.java:136)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalToBoolean(Expression.java:119)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalToBoolean(Expression.java:110)
    at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:46)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:312)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:62)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:312)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:290)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:312)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.renderTemplate(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:158)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.mergeTemplate(UIBean.java:584)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.ClosingUIBean.start(ClosingUIBean.java:57)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:54)
    at jsp_servlet._demotool.__fileupload._jsp__tag2(__fileupload.java:332)
    at jsp_servlet._demotool.__fileupload._jspService(__fileupload.java:236)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:408)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:318)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:502)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:432)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:163)
    at jsp_servlet._demotool.__ctmmessage._jspService(__ctmmessage.java:132)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:408)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:318)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:502)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:432)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:163)
    at jsp_servlet._demotool.__home._jspService(__home.java:255)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:408)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:318)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsExecuteFilter.java:90)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:91)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3496)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2086)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Comment: *I replaced the Struts core jar with struts2-core-**2.3.28.1** jar. Added struts2-dojo-plugin-**2.3.20.1*** : you do like problems, do you ? :D

Comment: It won't work anyway (the plugin is broken, I guess, and it is deprecated, so noone will ever fix it), but please, always follow the consistency in version numbers.

Comment: Thanks Andrea for your reply. This is the first time i am dealing with struts and trying whatever possible from my side to make it work. I now tried with struts2-dojo-plugin-2.3.28.1 but still get the same error. So my question is there a  way or a workaround to use Dojo tags with struts version 2.3.28.1?. If the answer is no, what is the best alternative to the Dojo tags which will involve minimum code change. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is I don't know :/ But you should consider migrating to a newer paradigm, either with struts2-jquery-plugin, or even better (to prevent problems like this for the future) to native jQuery. Once converted the 4-5 standard cases once, the other work is just repetitive, if you have 1000 pages using dojo tags you'll need to do it 1000 times, but after the first ones it'll be fast and known

Comment: dojo plugin is deprecated, you can't use it in new versions